# Set Up Django1.1.4 with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a project in Django 1.1.4 and I am trying to set up this project on production with mod_wsgi but I am getting some errors :

**My wsgi file code :**

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('path_to_\site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('path_to_dir')
sys.path.append('path_to_dir')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I have tried to debug the error like when I print something in my settings It doesn't get print so I guess my settings is not being called.

My wsgi and settings file are in the same level and I have used two ways to mention settings in my wsgi file like  `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'` and  `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'` but both fails.
.

**error - log :**

```
File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\functional.py", line 272, in __getattr__
     self._setup()
   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
     raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'cbc_website.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named cbc_website.settings
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean Django 1.1.4? Because 1.7 is the current version.

Comment: @omeinusch Yes, I am sure. It is a few years old website. so django 1.1.4 is being used.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.1.4/docs/howto/deployment/modwsgi.txt

Comment: Try adding the same dirs you're adding using sys.path.append to your shell PATH and check that you can import the settings file from a Python interpreter spawned from that shell.

Comment: Open the Python interpreter and try the following: `import sys; sys.path.append('path_to_dir'); import settings`. Where `path_to_dir' is the same path you're using in your `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: @dukebody its not importing the settings , However I have found one thing , when I print sys.path , interpreter is converting one of my folder name to hexadecimal e.g., its converting foldername **backup** to **x08ackup** , is this the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is interpreting your '\' in the path definitions as an escape character. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Use `r'path'` when specifying a literal path with backslashes. So instead of:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\\something')
```

You specify:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\\\something')
```

in your `wsgi.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import `yourprojectname.settings` instead of just `settings` ?

This is what I remenber doing, and what is specified in the link https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.1.4/docs/howto/deployment/modwsgi.txt provided in comments.

Comment: yes is have and I already mention this in my question that I have tried with both settings and project.settings